# Give Radon-measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ such that $\mu\ll\nu$ holds but $\nu\ll\mu$ fails

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I'm supposed to find Radon-measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ such that $\mu\ll\nu$ holds but $\nu\ll\mu$ fails. This seems too easy because I can take $\mu\equiv0$ and $\nu$ to be any non-zero Radon-measure (for example Lebesgue measure or Dirac measure). Then $\mu\ll \nu$ but $\nu\ll\mu$ is not true. Am I right or have I messed up something?

Comment: It's correct. Maybe you can try to give an example without using the zero measure.

Comment: @Rigel okay, can I do this without restricting the surrounding space $X$ or its topology, because all Radon measures I have in mind are Lebesgue, Dirac, counting (restricted), 0-1 -measure (restricted)?

Comment: Yes, sure. Your example is, in fact, the only one that is valid in general. (Consider the case of $X$ a singleton.)

Answer (score 1):

Your example is correct. To have an example with two nonzero measures $\mu$ and $\nu$, we should assume that the space has at least two points $a,b$; then $\mu=\delta_a$ and $\nu=\delta_a+\delta_b$ works.